# How to convert commas to dot in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, floating-point

I have a text file containing some data with 3 columns as below, how can I convert them to dots (float) in Python 3.5? Thank you in advance !

2,723   331,288 2,981592

2,701   331,208 2,980872

10,424  331,142 2,980278

18,261  331,21  2,98089

26,021  331,168 2,980512

I have tried this code below but it doesnot work:

`data = ""
with open('document.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace(', ',' ').replace('. ',' ')
    print(file.read())`

Comment: I think the file context is unnecessary here, can you show us how you would convert a string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.